# How to write where statement with AND condition in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables with Many to Many relationship.

1. Contact
2. Tag
3. ContactTag

   - contact_id
   - tag_id

Here is how Model looks:

```
class Contact extends Model{       
    public function tags()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'contact_tags', 'contact_id', 
     'tag_id');
    } 
  }
```

I want to retreive contacts only if it has both 'Sales Manager' and 'Product Manager' Tags. How to do that.

Here is my query.

```
$tags = ['Sales Manager','Product Manager'];

Contact::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tags){
   $query->whereIn($tags);
})
```

It returns contacts with either tags in 'Sales Manager' OR 'Product Manager. I want to do 'AND' condition. I tried this way too but it returns empty array.

```
  Contact::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
   $query->where('tags.name', $tags[0]);
   for ($i = 1; $i < count($tags); $i++) {
       $query->where('tags.name', $tags[$i]);
   }
  });
```

Comment: Double check if you have contact with both tags attached to it. In last block of code you can remove one line if you write `for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++) {`.

Comment: I do have contacts with both tags. Problem is if we chain multiple where conditions on same column name, it's not working. For example, $query->where('column1', 1)->where('column1', 2) would give empty array. So question is how to do AND operation.

Comment: If you want to enforce the connection between multiple tags, you'd probably have to do `$query = Contact::query()`, then `foreach($tags as $tag) { $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function ($subQuery) use ($tag) { return $subQuery->where('tags.name', $tag); }); }`, i.e. apply a `->whereHas()` for each individual Tag.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Slight change was we should not return $query in foreach loop but outside of it.
Updated code
$query = Contact::query(),
 foreach($tags as $tag) { 
       $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function ($subQuery) use ($tag) {  
             $subQuery->where('tags.name', $tag);  
       }); 
}
return $query;

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to do 2 exists checks, since you are checking for the existence of 2 things:

```
Contact::whereHas('tags', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'Sales Manager');
    })
    ->whereHas('tags', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'Product Manager');
    });
```